How can I get horizontal lines (with <hr> ONLY) to appear surrounding Font Awesome icon?
Problem
I'm trying to create a portfolio website, and I want to place a Font Awesome icon between two horizontal lines using <hr> elements, but it's not working. I've looked around Stack Overflow, and none of the solutions I've found have worked. This post was marked duplicate with a link to CSS technique for a horizontal line with words in the middle, but that only explains how to make the lines with pseudo-elements, not with <hr> elements.
What I Need
--------------- icon ---------------
So far, I have the code snippet below, and it makes space on the page for the lines, but they just aren't showing up. The icon is there just fine.
Code Snippet


html {
  background: #333;
}

.landing-content {
  height: calc(100vh - 40vh);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.landing-content h1 {
  font-size: calc(1.5rem + 4vw);
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #e8e8e8;
}

.landing-content p {
  font-size: calc(0.6rem + 0.5vw);
  color: #e8e8e8;
}

.landing-content a {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: transparent;
  color: #e8e8e8;
  border: 2px solid #e8e8e8;
  border-radius: 1em;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.landing-content a:hover {
  background: #e8e8e8;
  color: black;
  border-color: transparent;
}

.title-line {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 0;
  color: #e8e8e8;
  padding-bottom: 0.6%;
}

.title-line hr {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: none;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
}

.title-line .icon {
  margin: 0 10px;
  color: #e8e8e8;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css">


<div class="landing-content">
  <h1 class="title">My Name</h1>
  <div class="title-line">
    <hr>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-user-astronaut fa-xl icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <p><q>Stellar quote</q> <span class=nowrap>- Smart Person</span></p>
  <a href="#">Get Started</a>
</div>




The border: none attribute is hiding the lines.
You may also want to set a width for them. I did this directly on the hr in my example below, but you could alternatively set width: 100% (or other % of your choice) on the parent element's class.


html {
  background: #333;
}

.landing-content {
  height: calc(100vh - 40vh);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.landing-content h1 {
  font-size: calc(1.5rem + 4vw);
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #e8e8e8;
}

.landing-content p {
  font-size: calc(0.6rem + 0.5vw);
  color: #e8e8e8;
}

.landing-content a {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: transparent;
  color: #e8e8e8;
  border: 2px solid #e8e8e8;
  border-radius: 1em;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.landing-content a:hover {
  background: #e8e8e8;
  color: black;
  border-color: transparent;
}

.title-line {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 0;
  color: #e8e8e8;
  padding-bottom: 0.6%;
}

.title-line hr {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 50px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
}

.title-line .icon {
  margin: 0 10px;
  color: #e8e8e8;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css">


<div class="landing-content">
  <h1 class="title">My Name</h1>
  <div class="title-line">
    <hr>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-user-astronaut fa-xl icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <p><q>Remember to look up at the stars and not down at your feet.</q> <span class=nowrap>- Stephen Hawking</span></p>
  <a href="#">Get Started</a>
</div>




I'd rather do this with CSS than extra markup. Pseudo-elements on your line element could work well. You eliminate the rule elements and are left with roughly the same amount of CSS. Note that the margin on the icon is no longer needed.


html {
  background: #333;
}

.landing-content {
  height: calc(100vh - 40vh);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.landing-content h1 {
  font-size: calc(1.5rem + 4vw);
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #e8e8e8;
}

.landing-content p {
  font-size: calc(0.6rem + 0.5vw);
  color: #e8e8e8;
}

.landing-content a {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: transparent;
  color: #e8e8e8;
  border: 2px solid #e8e8e8;
  border-radius: 1em;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.landing-content a:hover {
  background: #e8e8e8;
  color: black;
  border-color: transparent;
}

.title-line {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 20px 0;
  color: #e8e8e8;
  padding-bottom: 0.6%;
}

 /* -------------- STARTING HERE -------------- */
.title-line::before,
.title-line::after {
  content: '';
  width: 10%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #e8e8e8;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% + 1.5rem);
}

.title-line::after {
  left: auto;
  right: calc(50% + 1.5rem);
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css">


<div class="landing-content">
  <h1 class="title">My Name</h1>
  
  <div class="title-line">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-user-astronaut fa-xl icon wings" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>

  <p><q>Remember to look up at the stars and not down at your feet.</q> <span class=nowrap>- Stephen Hawking</span></p>
  
  <a href="#">Get Started</a>
</div>



